# How to load file locally with path vs path in Azure Devops build

Tags: sql-server, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to load a file in my PostDeployment script in my DB project:

```
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'C:\Development\MyProject.Db\Scripts\My_Script.sql',SINGLE_CLOB)
```

Of course my build pipeline in azure devops is complaining that cannot find this script. But when I change it to the following my local build complains:

```
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyProject.Db\Scripts\My_Script.sql',SINGLE_CLOB)
```

What is the right way here? I would like to keep my local path locally and switch to the build one (hoping that one is the correct one, didn't even get the chance to try it cause the build complains) when the Azure Pipeline build runs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Post Deployment scripts will run on the servers once the databases have been deployed successfully to the servers. So, you can't directly use the absolute (or relative) paths in the scripts to access the local machines.

In Azure Pipelines, if we want to access the remote services from the local machines, we have many existing methods and tasks to create and use the service connections to access the services.

However, for the reverse visit that access the local machines from the remote services, we have no existing, easy ways. As far as I know, you may need to map the IP address and port of the local machine on the remote services, and you also may need to configure proxy settings, firewall settings on the local machines.

If the files you want to access in the Post Deployment scripts have been deployed to the servers, you can directly use these file paths on the servers instead of the local machines.

**[UPDATE]**

Each pipeline will be assigned with a working directory (**`$(Pipeline.Workspace)`**) in the working directory for the agent (**`$(Agent.WorkFolder)`**).

If the files you want to access are the source files in the source repository, and the repository has been checked out to the working directory for the pipeline, you can access the source files in the directory **`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`**.

**`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`** is the default working directory of the job, so you can access the source files using either relative paths or absolute paths.

For example:

- Using relative path.

`MyProject.Db/Scripts/My_Script.sql`

OR

`./MyProject.Db/Scripts/My_Script.sql`

- Using absolute path.

`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyProject.Db/Scripts/My_Script.sql`

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all. My scenario is the last one, my files can be deployed to the servers. The problem is that the Azure Pipeline runs with an agent that is not self hosted. Hence I cannot bring physically my script on that "server" where the agent is.

Comment: Hi @Tarta, I have updated my answer with more information. Please check it. Any questions about this, feel free to tell me.